# Is there a way to convert an odd length hexadecimal string to bytearray, or can an odd length bytearray exist in python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

This has been a point of pain in my application, as I specifically need to send an odd number of hex values to a device in byte array form. I know `binascii.unhexlify()` or `bytes.fromhex()` will not take an odd length string, but I'm wondering if theres an alternative to producing an odd length bytearray.  Any insight would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: can you give an example of your odd length hex values

Comment: It can be something as trivial as like 0xF, 0x1, in string format 'F' etc.

Comment: what about something like `print(bytearray(hex(int('F',16)).encode()))` gives output `bytearray(b'0xf')`

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work.  Byte array need  b'x\01', a full byte which I know is the obvious answer, I was hoping their might be a half byte array or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions to split on either `x` or `X`, then add a leading zero.

```py
import binascii
import re

def make_even_hexstr(hex_str):
    lhs, rhs = re.split(r"x|X", hex_str)
    if bool(len(rhs) % 2):
        return "".join(["0", rhs])
    return rhs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hex_str = "0xF"
    print(f"{hex_str}:", make_even_hexstr(hex_str))
    binascii.unhexlify(make_even_hexstr(hex_str))

    hex_str = "0x02"
    print(f"{hex_str}:", make_even_hexstr(hex_str))
    binascii.unhexlify(make_even_hexstr(hex_str))

    hex_str = "0xF23"
    print(f"{hex_str}:", make_even_hexstr(hex_str))
    binascii.unhexlify(make_even_hexstr(hex_str))
```